# Kentico Custom Page Type Form Validation Conditional Require

Tags: kentico

For fields in a custom page type, what is the effective way to access the value of the current field for validation purposes within a macro or Rule designer? Is it just `Value`? Is it `FieldName.Value`? `this.Value`?

The goal is to add a validation rule that satisfies a macro condition (General condition) for a **custom page type** creation form. For example, if I wanted to make sure the string value of a text field with **Field name** of `Foobar` is not empty/null, how would I set that up as a **General condition** validation rule?

Trying either of the following:

```
Satisfies macro condition {% !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) %}
Satisfies macro condition {% !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Foobar.Value) %}
```

Gives an error when attempting to save a value for `Foobar` field when it **has** a string value with length greater than zero (0). Validation strangely passes when the field is empty.

This `Foobar` field "Depends on another field:". It will be required only if **another** field is a certain value. Within the macro rule, I am able to access other field values using `OtherField.Value`, that is why simply adding a "Minimum length" rule will not work in this case. I was hoping to use something to extent of the following to check the condition of checkbox (checked/True) to conditionally require this text field, but the string/text evaluation of `Foobar`, the current field isn't working.

```
{% if (OtherField.Value == True) { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Foobar.Value) } else { return true; } %}
```

**Note:** I can evaluate `OtherField.Value`/`OtherField.Length` in `Foobar`'s properties, even such as "Explanation text". I can also evaluate `Foobar.Value` in `OtherField`'s properties. They have values/lengths/etc.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

K# is case-insensitive ALTHOUGH and almost all of the C# methods are available in K# but letter case may have an effect in the values of constants and variables (for the purposes of comparisons and similar). And I don't believe `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is available in the macro engine, but I could be wrong.

So to get to your issue you could do something like:

```
{% if(OtherField.Value) { Foobar.Value != "" } else { true } %}
```

Also have you tried the [Macro debugger](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/troubleshooting-macros/debugging-macros) to see what your output values are and what the macro is processing?  This would be a good test to setup.

[Macro methods](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/reference-macro-methods)

Comment: To clarify, you're supposed to access the field's value by targeting the field/code name as in `FieldName.Value`? It's not just `Value` or `this.Value` or `CurrentContextSomething.Value`?

Comment: Correct its ColumnName.Value.